# Fatal error encountered during command execution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Trying to check Entered Username is Already exists in the Database or not. but Above Error Rises.

```
protected void txtUsername_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(con1);
        try{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUsername.Text))
        {


            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select username from client_login where username=@Name", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                checkusername.Visible = true;
                imgstatus.ImageUrl = "NotAvailable.jpg";
                lblStatus.Text = "UserName Already Taken";
            }
            else
            {
                checkusername.Visible = true;
                imgstatus.ImageUrl = "Icon_Available.gif";
                lblStatus.Text = "UserName Available";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            checkusername.Visible = false;
        }
        con.Close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex){
            Response.Write(ex);
        }

    }
```

and textBox code is Below

```
` <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtUsername_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>`
```

Error is At Execute Reader as
base = {"Fatal error encountered during command execution."}

Comment: Add the stacktrace.

Comment: stackTrace is not produced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fill your parameter in your sql query. Like:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtUsername.Text);
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much Sir , it is Working